# C# combit.ListLabel27 missing using reference error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Everything is installed and everything is ready, but this problem occurs during compilation:

Error 296 The type or namespace name 'combit' could not be found. (Missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: Why not try control+click or go to nuget to add it?

Comment: I tried to install it as a nuget package, but that's not the problem, the problem was due to the .net version difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we were able to solve it after a long time.

**Our Project Version**
Our project runs on .net 4.5.2.

**Plugin Version**
The latest version of Combit.Reporting is .net version 4.7.

In other words, it will not give any error, but it will prevent your project from compiling because the .net versions do not match.

**Attention!**

> If you want to connect a project that needs a higher .net version to
> your project, consider the above article.